# How can I show that if $x$ is a nonunit then $1-x$ is a unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings

> Let $R$ be a commutative local ring. I want to show that then $x\in R$ is not a unit implies $1-x$ is a unit.

My idea was the following:

Since $R$ is a local ring we can chose $\mathfrak{m}$  to be it's unique maximal ideal. Now let $x\in R$ be a nonunit and assume that $1-x$ is also a nonunit. Then $I:=(1-x)\subsetneq R$. Since $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal $I\subseteq \mathfrak{m}$. Now I wanted to write $1=1-x+x$ and I can deduce that $1-x+x$ is a unit. But somehow I don't see how to conclude from there. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: The set of non-units is equal to $\mathfrak{m}$. Can you prove that if $x \in \mathfrak{m}$ then $1-x \notin \mathfrak{m}$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg no sorry I don't see a way of doing it

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I think I need to find $z$ s.t. $(1-x)z=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $R$ is local with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, then $R^{\times} = R \setminus \mathfrak{m}$. See for example [SE/3913530](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3913530).
2. If $R$ is any ring and $I \subseteq R$ is any proper ideal, then $x \in I$ implies $1-x \notin I$. In fact, if $1-x \in I$, then $1 = x + (1-x) \in I$, so $I = R$.

The claim follows from 1. and 2.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: I searched for like 5 mins and couldn't find it. PS: You dont have to write these comments anymore to me. I know your policy.

Comment: It's not *my* policy - it is *site* policy that is now being enforced (users who ignore it have been suspended - including some high rep users). If it seems likely that it is a dupe please delay answering so that it can be properly processed by others.